# Timer goes to be destroyed only via null assignment, instead of clearTimeout()

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to figure out why my simple throttle func is not working correctly by destroying previous one timer via `clearTimeout()`. It's just doesn't work, only `null` assignment gets me up from this pitfall...

Any idea why? Thanks

Code:

```
const throttler = ({ event, callback, delay, target }) => {
  let timerID = null
  const eventSubscribeTarget = target || window

  const resizeThrottler = () => {
    if (timerID) return

    timerID = setTimeout(() => {
      callback()
      timerID = null // <= only by null assigment it's gonna gone...
      // clearTimeout(timerID) doesn't work here
    }, delay)
  }

  eventSubscribeTarget.addEventListener(event, resizeThrottler, false)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, call `clearTimeout` with `timerID`, and then set the `timerID` to `null`.

What you are currently doing is to set the `timerID` to `null`; thereby losing the `timerID` value. The code is essentially doing `clearTimeout(null)` instead of `clearTimeout(20) // assuming timerID = 20`.

Moreover, only setting your `timerID` to `null` will not cancel the timeout event: it will still run. So, to avoid memory leaks and unpredictable behaviors in a program which is repeatedly invoking the `setTimeout` function like yours seems to be doing, `clearTimeout` with your `timerID` is a must. You can set your `timerID` to `null` after that if you want.

Answer (score 0):

(`clearTimeout` - `clearInterval` mixup aside...)
Here:

```
    if (timerID) return
```

So setting the timerId value to null will cause the early return here, new timeout won't be set. Exactly what we're after, I presume.

```
    timerID = setTimeout(() => {
      callback()
      timerID = null // <= only by null assigment it's gonna gone...
      // clearTimeout(timerID) doesn't work here
```

And here, `clearTimeout` wouldn't do a thing - the timeout has already ticked, the callback has already been called, there's really no longer a timeout to clear. The function is being executed right here, and won't be again. If we want to prevent new timeout being set, then this

```
    timerID = setTimeout(() => {
```

is the line that can't be executed.

Comment: Sorry, I made a type. I've used the `clearTimeout` to deal with timer...

Comment: > there's really no longer a timeout to clear --- nope, the timer `ID` inside the `timerID` variable already stored (I see it by `console.log()`) during setTimeout running, but `clearTimeout()` doesn't get it in...

Comment: Yes, but first the value of what's inside `setTimeout()` is evaluated, and _then_ it's assigned the new value. `clearTimeout` clears _old_ timeout.

Comment: Nope, I've exactly the same timer `ID` that is just doesn't gonna to destroy during all updates inside function...

Answer (score 0):

The result of the `setTimeout()` always returns a `Number`. This number represents the ID value of the timer that is set. Use this value with the `clearTimeout()` method to cancel the timer.

The clearTimeout function will not reset the number, that is why you have to set your `timerID` to `null` when you want to reuse this variable.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: I know all what you mention above, meanwhile it's doesn't a solution nor a focus of the pitfall, because my timer ID is stored in `timedID` variable, but for some reasons `clearTimeout()` doesn't see it correctly...